# How can I use file field label as clickable download link or replace field discription (file title)?

Tags: theming, nodes, 8, entities, files

I created a file field that's have it's own desired label and should display in a node content; I'm using 'generic files' setting to display it; the problem is that this file has really ugly names like '102-32.exe' and I'd like to change the name of it to '**File field label**'.

For example:

> **File field Label**: [102-32.exe](http://#)
>  Change to below (Automatic download field):
>   **[File field Label](http://#)**

Comment: you only want to change the name of files which have ugly names ?? or change all the file names ??

Comment: You can create a  field formatter and then assign it

Comment: just a clarification you want to change the title of download link for all files right

Comment: file formatter is little tedious job why not try file_presave                                                        function yourmodulename_file_presave($file) {
  $parts = pathinfo($file->filename);
  $file->filename = 'custom name' ;
}

Comment: U can hide the label and change file name as file field label...